# Needing input field to toggle

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm finishing up an online movie library and I have an "Add to List" button that works without a page refresh. It works great but it doesn't toggle, which ultimately I need it to do. I need to be able to add and then remove without a page refresh. Right now the if/else targets two seperate functions. I'm terrible with JavaScript and have tried hacking it together using various example from StackOverflow, but I haven't been successful. I'm not strong enough with Javascript to figure this out, or to modify other people's code to get it to work. Any help getting this to toggle would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

**Main code**

```
<div id="content-new">
    <?php   
    $sql_action = "SELECT movies.img, movies.title, movies.title_full, movies.new, my_list.title, my_list.username FROM movies LEFT JOIN my_list ON movies.title_full = my_list.title WHERE new != '' ORDER BY movies.id DESC LIMIT 16";
    $result_action = mysqli_query( $db_connect, $sql_action )or die( mysqli_error( $db_connect ) );
    while ( $row_action = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result_action ) ) {
      $img = $row_action[ 'img' ];
      $title = $row_action[ 'title' ];
      $title_full = $row_action[ 'title_full' ];
      $new = $row_action [ 'new' ];
      $mylist = $row_action[ 'username' ];
        
      // CHECK IF FAV EXISTS MORE THAN ONCE IN DB
      $stmt_count_fav = $db_connect->prepare("SELECT title FROM my_list WHERE title = ?"); 
      $stmt_count_fav->bind_param("s", $title_full);
      $stmt_count_fav -> execute();
      $stmt_count_fav -> store_result();
      $stmt_count_fav -> fetch();
      $count_fav = $stmt_count_fav->num_rows;
      $stmt_count_fav->close();
      ?>
    
<div id="div_fav_hover">
<form id="form-new" style="padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;" method="post" action="movie.php">
    <input id="btn_top" style="display: none" type="text" name="latest" id="latest" value="<?php if ($title_full == '') {echo $title;} else {echo $title_full;} ?>" />
    <?php if ($mylist == $username) { ?>      
    <input id="new_releases" type="image" name="image" src="images/<?php echo $img ?>">
    <?php } else if ($count_fav <= 1) { ?>
    <input id="new_releases" type="image" name="image" src="images/<?php echo $img ?>">
    <?php } ?>
</form>

<?php if ( $mylist == $username) { // ON MY LIST ?> 
<div class="div_new_delete">
  <form id="form-new" class="class_new_delete">
    <input style="display: none" type="text" name="title_home" value="<?php echo $title_full; ?>" />
    <input style="display: none" name="favorite_delete_home" value="favorite_delete_home" />
    <input id="btn_mylist_on_home" type="submit" name="btn_password" value="" class="class_fav_hover_on">
  </form>
</div>
<?php } else if ($count_fav <= 1) { // ON NO ONE'S LIST ?>
<div class="div_new_add">
  <form id="form-new" class="class_new_add">
    <input style="display: none" type="text" name="title_home" value="<?php echo $title_full; ?>" />
    <input style="display: none" name="favorite_home" value="favorite_home" />
    <input id="btn_mylist_off_home" type="submit" name="btn_password" value="" class="class_fav_hover_off">
  </form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>

<?php } // END LOOP ?>
        
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.class_new_add').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax/mylist.php',
      context:$(this),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $(this).closest("div").html("<div class=\"div_new_delete\"><form id=\"form-new\" class=\"class_new_delete\"><input style=\"display: none\" type=\"text\" name=\"title_home\" value=\"<?php echo $title_full; ?>\" /><input style=\"display: none\" name=\"favorite_delete_home\" value=\"favorite_delete_home\" /><input id=\"btn_mylist_off_home\" type=\"submit\" name=\"btn_password\" value=\"\" class=\"class_fav_hover_on\"></form></div>")
      }
    });
  });
});
$(function() {
  $('.class_new_delete').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax/mylist.php',
      context:$(this),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $(this).closest("div").html("<div class=\"div_new_add\"><form id=\"form-new\" class=\"class_new_add\"><input style=\"display: none\" type=\"text\" name=\"title_home\" value=\"<?php echo $title_full; ?>\" /><input style=\"display: none\" name=\"favorite_home\" value=\"favorite_home\" /><input id=\"btn_mylist_on_home\" type=\"submit\" name=\"btn_password\" value=\"\" class=\"class_fav_hover_off\"></form></div>")
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
</div>
```

**ajax/mylist.php**

```
<?php

include "../includes/db_connector.php"; ?>

<?php if ( isset( $_POST[ 'favorite_home' ] )) { // HOMEPAGE AJAX ATTEMPT       
$stmt_favorites = $db_connect->prepare("INSERT INTO my_list (title, username) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt_favorites->bind_param("ss", $title_home, $username);
$title_home = $_POST['title_home'];
$result=$stmt_favorites->execute();
$stmt_favorites->close();  
} ?>

<?php if ( isset( $_POST[ 'favorite_delete_home' ] )) { // HOMEPAGE AJAX ATTEMPT
$stmt_favorites = $db_connect->prepare("DELETE FROM my_list WHERE title = ? AND username = ?");
$stmt_favorites->bind_param("ss", $title_home, $username);
$title_home = $_POST['title_home'];
$result=$stmt_favorites->execute();
$stmt_favorites->close();
} ?>
```

**Updated if/else input fields**

```
<?php if ( $mylist == $username) { // ON MY LIST ?> 
  <form id="form-new" class="class_new_delete">
    <input style="display: none" type="text" name="title_home" value="<?php echo $title_full; ?>" />
    <input style="display: none" name="favorite_delete_home" value="favorite_delete_home" />
    <input id="btn_mylist_on_home" type="submit" name="btn_mylist_on_home" value="" class="class_fav_hover_on">
  </form>
<?php } else if ($count_fav <= 1) { // ON NO ONE'S LIST ?>
  <form id="form-new" class="class_new_add">
    <input style="display: none" type="text" name="title_home" value="<?php echo $title_full; ?>" />
    <input style="display: none" name="favorite_home" value="favorite_home" />
    <input id="btn_mylist_off_home" type="submit" name="btn_mylist_off_home" value="" class="class_fav_hover_off">
  </form>
<?php } ?>
```

**Updated JavaScript**

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $(this).find('.class_new_add').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax/mylist.php',
      context:$(this),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $(this).closest('.class_new_add').html("<input id=\"btn_mylist_off_home\" type=\"submit\" name=\"btn_password\" value=\"\" class=\"class_fav_hover_on\">")
      }
    });
  });
});
$(function() {
  $(this).find('.class_new_delete').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax/mylist.php',
      context:$(this),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $(this).closest('.class_new_delete').html("<input id=\"btn_mylist_on_home\" type=\"submit\" name=\"btn_password\" value=\"\" class=\"class_fav_hover_off\">")
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you need to get the data from PHP through the request `success: function(data) {}` data is the response from your server, use that to fill the html instead `<?php echo $title_full; ?>` because that is hardcoded into your script. also after you do such html modifications you have to bind the submit event to these, because the `$(function() { ... })` is jQuery shorthand for document.ready event, so function is executed just once, call `.on('submit', ...)` on the modified html like `$(this).find('.class_new_delete').on('submit', ...);`

Comment: @Kazz. Thanks for responding! I've looked this over carefully and am having a hard time understanding how to implement this. I apologize, I'm more of a designer than a coder... If you have the time to provide an example that'd be great.

Comment: i'm sorry, stackoverflow is not write code for me service, you should either learn or leave it, in case you choose learning there is plenty of resources.

Comment: I respect that. I'm def here to learn - I'll keep digging. Thanks again!

Comment: I added my updated code to my original post. It seems like a cleaner approach, but clearly it hasn't solved my problem. Where I'm getting confused is what exactly to use the success data for. In my mind it should be used to display the submit button (which I have it), since that's what needs to change on submit, but clearly I'm missing something based on your earlier reply.

Could you clarify what you mean by "using the success to populate the html instead <?php echo $title_full ?> since that's hardcoded into my script?" That's where I'm getting thrown off.

Comment: First, I know it was discussed in another question, but you don't want to reuse IDs and its easy to not use them anyway. So I would get rid of the ID in the HTML. Also, in your jquery you don't have to escape the double quotes, you can just use single quotes. so instead of type=\"submit\", you can just use type='submit'. Switching won't solve anything but will be cleaner for you. So with that being said, what do you actually want to happen in your success function? Just toggle a class on your button that is already in the form?

Comment: imvain2, thanks for the suggestions - I'll make those changes right away! Yes, toggle the class on my button is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I know I answered a previous question about this project. So I'm going to copy over my answer from there and modify it here as this is a different question.

There are a few ways to do what you are looking for.

For my answer, I'm asking if you change your CSS classes to be a tad different. This will also help in future projects as this is a common way to accomplish this concept.

Instead of using **class_fav_hover_off** and **class_fav_hover_on** Have one class for the buttons, **class_fav_hover** This will be the equivalent to **class_fav_hover_off**. Then instead of using **class_fav_hover_on** you use **class_fav_hover** with an additional class of **active**.

So for the on button:

```
<input type="submit" name="btn_mylist_on_home" value="" class="class_fav_hover active">
```

So for the off button:

```
<input type="submit" name="btn_mylist_on_home" value="" class="class_fav_hover">
```

The advantage of this, is you can easily toggle a single class. In this case the class would be called "active".

Then in your ajax success, just use `$(this).find("[type='submit']").toggleClass("active")` to search for a button that has type submit.

The toggle the class of active.

The beauty of this method, is you can use the SAME code for your delete and add success. This works because if the button has active, toggle will remove it. If the button doesn't have it, toggle will add it.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.class_new_add').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Adding please wait");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'https://httpbin.org/post',
      context:$(this),
      data: {"key": "value"},
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("Added");
        $(this).find("[type='submit']").toggleClass("active")
      }
    });
  });
  
$('.class_new_delete').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Deleting please wait");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'https://httpbin.org/post',
      context:$(this),
      data: {"key": "value"},
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("Deleted");
        $(this).find("[type='submit']").toggleClass("active")
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.class_fav_hover{
  background:#fffaaa;
}

.class_fav_hover.active{
  background:#000AAA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div_new_add" style="display: inline-block;">
  <form id="form-new" style="display: inline-block;" class="class_new_add">
    <input style="display: none" type="text" name="title_home" value="<?php echo $title_full; ?>" />
    <input style="display: none" name="favorite_home" value="favorite_home" />
    <input type="submit" name="btn_password" value="ADD" class="class_fav_hover active">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="div_new_add" style="display: inline-block;">
  <form id="form-new" style="display: inline-block;" class="class_new_delete">
    <input style="display: none" type="text" name="title_home" value="<?php echo $title_full; ?>" />
    <input style="display: none" name="favorite_home" value="favorite_home" />
    <input type="submit" name="btn_password" value="DELETE" class="class_fav_hover">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help - again!!! the class is toggling beautifully, but it's not updating the db correctly. In my original code, within the if/else, the second inputs had different names... "favorite_home" and "favorite_delete_home". On success, within ajax/mylist.php, those names determine if the favorite is added or removed from the db. so it seems i need to not just toggle the style, but the entire form? thanks again for you help.